# Solving the equation $\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = -x(t)$ using a Fourier transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am trying to understand the frequency domain and Fourier transforms by using them to solve simple differential equations. In particular, I am interested in the equation:
$$
dx(t) =  x(t)dt  \quad \text{or} \quad \frac{dx}{dt} = -x  \quad \text{with } x(0)=x_{0}
$$
Clearly a solution to this is $x(t) = x_0 e^{-t}$. However, I fail to recover this result when attempting to solve using the Fourier transform.

I will use the follwing conventions for the Fourier transform:
$$x(\omega) = \mathcal{F}[x(t)] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(t) e^{i \omega t} dt \, ,$$
and its inverse $$x(t) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}[x(\omega)] =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(\omega) e^{-i \omega t} d\omega \, .$$

Fourier transforming both sides of $\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = -x(t)$ gives:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx(t)}{dt} e^{i \omega t} dt = -x(\omega) .
$$
The left hand side can be expanded using integration by parts:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx(t)}{dt} e^{i \omega t} dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\big[x(t)e^{i \omega t} \big]^{+\infty}_{-\infty} - i \omega x(\omega)
$$
To proceed, we need boundary conditions of $x(t)$ at $t = \pm \infty$, which we do not have as part of the original problem. Normally, when dealing with Fourier transforms, we assume $x\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow \pm \infty$. If we do this, (even though this is not the correct boundary condition at $t\rightarrow -\infty$) the equation becomes:
$$
-i \omega x(\omega) = x(\omega)\quad  \text{ which yields } \quad x(\omega)=0
$$
Inverting the Fourier transform of $x(\omega) = 0$ yields $x(t)=0$. This is the steady state solution as $t\rightarrow \infty$, but does not yield the correct solution $x(t) = x_0 e^{-t}$.

How do I correctly solve this simple equation using the Fourier transform?

Comment: Read through https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1276523/fourier-transform-conditions , which may shed some light on your problem.

Comment: Thanks for that. I see that the Fourier does not exist for this system. Apologies for the late response.